# Filtering variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I wrote some code to implement a way to filter the arguments of a variadic template based on their type.

My current solution requires many helper meta-functions and I'm sure that there must be a better way. How would you improve this?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

//Type for storing a variadic template
template <typename ...>
struct list {};

//helper meta-functions

//list_rename function. Renames any template type. Needed to convert list to tuple later
template <typename source, template <typename ...> class TargetT>
struct list_rename_impl;

template <template <typename ...> class SourceT, typename ... Args, template <typename ...> class TargetT>
struct list_rename_impl<SourceT<Args...>, TargetT>
{
    using type = TargetT<Args...>;
};

template <typename source, template <typename ...> class TargetT>
using list_rename = typename list_rename_impl<source, TargetT>::type;
//~END list_rename

//list_append function. Appends List U to T. Needed for the list_on_condition function
template <typename T, typename U>
struct list_append_impl
{};

template <typename ... LHS, typename ... RHS>
struct list_append_impl<list<LHS...>, list<RHS...>>
{
    using type = list<LHS..., RHS...>;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
using list_append = typename list_append_impl<T, U>::type;
//~END list_append


//list_on_condition function. Creates a list of all passed Elements for which Condition<Element>::value is true.
//This way a parameter pack can be filtered on a condition and stored 
template <template <typename> class Condition, typename ... Elements>
struct list_on_condition_impl
{};

template <template <typename> class Condition>
struct list_on_condition_impl<Condition>
{
    using type = list<>; //No more elements to left, return empty list
};

template <template <typename> class Condition, typename Element>
struct list_on_condition_impl<Condition, Element>
{
    using type = typename std::conditional //Only one element left. Return it, if it fullfills the Condition
                 <
                    Condition<Element>::value,
                    list<Element>,
                    list<>
                 >::type;
};

template <template <typename> class Condition, typename Element, typename ... Elements>
struct list_on_condition_impl<Condition, Element, Elements...>
{
    using type = list_append //Check the first element and append it to the others recursively
                 <
                    typename std::conditional
                    //Current element  gets wrapped in a list, if it fullfills the Condition,
                    //otherwise it resolves to an empty list 
                    <
                        Condition<Element>::value,
                        list<Element>,
                        list<>
                    >::type,
                    //self recursion
                    typename list_on_condition_impl

                    <
                        Condition,
                        Elements...
                    >::type
                 >;
};

template <template <typename> class Condition, typename ... Elements>
using list_on_condition = typename list_on_condition_impl<Condition, Elements...>::type;
//~ END helpers

//A dummy struct
template <typename ... Args>
struct A
{};

//Another dummy struct
template <typename ... Args>
struct B {};

//The actual testcase struct
template <typename ... Args> //This variadic template has to be filtered
class C
{
    private:
        //condition meta-functions; Decide if the template parameter is an A<...> or a B<...>
        template <typename T>
        struct IsA : std::false_type {};

        template <typename ... Elements>
        struct IsA<A<Elements...>> : std::true_type{};

        template <typename T>
        struct IsB : std::false_type {};

        template <typename ... Elements>
        struct IsB<B<Elements...>> : std::true_type{};

    public:
        using As = list_on_condition<IsA, Args...>; //Filtering using the helper functions from above
        using Bs = list_on_condition<IsB, Args...>;

        using ATuple = list_rename<As, std::tuple>; //Converting the list container to a tuple type 
        using BTuple = list_rename<Bs, std::tuple>;

        ATuple m_ATuple; //The template arguments in separated tuples
        BTuple m_BTuple;
};

int main()
{
    //Some checks to proof, that it works
    using t1 = C<A<int>, B<int>>;

    static_assert(   std::is_same
                     <
                       typename t1::As,
                       list<A<int>>
                     >::value
                  && std::is_same
                     <
                       typename t1::Bs,
                       list<B<int>>
                     >::value, "!!");

    using t2 = C<A<int>, B<int>, A<double, int>, A<float>, B<long>>;

    static_assert(   std::is_same
                     <
                       typename t2::As,
                       list<A<int>, A<double, int>, A<float>>
                     >::value
                  && std::is_same
                     <
                       typename t2::Bs,
                       list<B<int>, B<long>>
                     >::value, "!!");

    //Is there a more elegant way of filtering variadic templates?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One reason you think you require a lot of helper metafunctions is that you haven't clearly separated the code for *solving the problem* (filtering a list) from the code for *testing the solution* (e.g. `list_rename` and `A`, `B`, `C`).

Your actual *solving the problem* code, with redundant comments and newlines removed, boils down to this:

```
template <typename ...> struct list {};

template <typename T, typename U> struct list_append_impl {};

template <typename ... LHS, typename ... RHS>
struct list_append_impl<list<LHS...>, list<RHS...>> {
    using type = list<LHS..., RHS...>;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
using list_append = typename list_append_impl<T, U>::type;

template <template <typename> class Condition, typename ... Elements>
struct list_on_condition_impl {};

template <template <typename> class Condition>
struct list_on_condition_impl<Condition> {
    using type = list<>;
};

template <template <typename> class Condition, typename Element>
struct list_on_condition_impl<Condition, Element> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<
                    Condition<Element>::value,
                    list<Element>,
                    list<>
                 >::type;
};

template <template <typename> class Condition, typename Element, typename ... Elements>
struct list_on_condition_impl<Condition, Element, Elements...> {
    using type = list_append<
                    typename std::conditional<
                        Condition<Element>::value,
                        list<Element>,
                        list<>
                    >::type,
                    typename list_on_condition_impl<
                        Condition,
                        Elements...
                    >::type
                 >;
};

template <template <typename> class Condition, typename ... Elements>
using list_on_condition = typename list_on_condition_impl<Condition, Elements...>::type;
```

That's not particularly concise, but it's much less bad than you originally thought it was.

So let's work on removing the unnecessary parts. First of all, you have *three* specializations of `list_on_condition_impl`; that's a red flag, because you should basically always have two specializations of any recursive template — you should have one base case and one recursive case. If you have *two* base cases, something is probably wrong. You can safely remove the middle case,

```
template <template <typename> class Condition, typename Element>
struct list_on_condition_impl<Condition, Element> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<
                    Condition<Element>::value,
                    list<Element>,
                    list<>
                 >::type;
};
```

, because that case (an `Elements` list of length 1) will be handled perfectly fine by the recursive case.

---

Next, a style/safety note: For metaprogramming, you don't need to provide full definitions (i.e. class bodies) for your types; a declaration is usually all you need. Furthermore, providing just the declarations will prevent the user from accidentally trying to define variables of those types. So, for example, you should write

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct list_append_impl;
```

instead of

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct list_append_impl {};
```

and so on throughout. This also means that if someone accidentally tries to refer to `list_append_impl<int, int>::type`, they'll get a hard compiler error `implicit instantiation of undefined template 'list_append_impl<int, int>'` instead of a SFINAE-friendly error `no type named 'type' in 'list_append_impl<int, int>'`.

---

Next: Since `list_append_impl` is just an implementation detail, you probably don't need to define a convenience alias `list_append` for it. You could just use `typename list_append_impl<...>::type` in the couple of places you need it. This would kill off three more lines.

---

I also suggest naming the metafunction `filter`, instead of `list_on_condition`; the former conveys exactly what the metafunction is supposed to do, while the latter is pretty opaque to anybody reading the code.

Similarly, I'd recommend `Predicate` over `Condition`, `Ts...` and `Us...` over `LHS...` and `RHS...`, and `T` and `Rest...` over `Element` and `Elements...`.

And for parameters whose names don't matter because they're unused — remove the unused names! (Unless you use a documentation-generation tool that needs the names for some reason, I guess.)

---

Consider using `std::conditional_t<x,y,z>` in place of `typename std::conditional<x,y,z>::type`, if you're using a recent enough C++14 library.

---

With the above suggestions and a bit of trivial whitespace formatting (e.g., `typename...` in place of `typename ...`), we get this:

```
template <typename...> struct list;

template <typename, typename> struct list_append_impl;

template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct list_append_impl<list<Ts...>, list<Us...>> {
    using type = list<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template <template <typename> class, typename...>
struct filter_impl;

template <template <typename> class Predicate>
struct filter_impl<Predicate> {
    using type = list<>;
};

template <template <typename> class Predicate, typename T, typename... Rest>
struct filter_impl<Predicate, T, Rest...> {
    using type = typename list_append_impl<
                    std::conditional_t<
                        Predicate<T>::value,
                        list<T>,
                        list<>
                    >,
                    typename filter_impl<Predicate, Rest...>::type
                 >::type;
};

template <template <typename> class Predicate, typename... Ts>
using filter = typename filter_impl<Predicate, Ts...>::type;
```

---

One minor improvement you could make would be to split out the subproblem of "concatenating an arbitrary number of `list`s", so that you could write `filter_impl` without the recursion.

```
template <typename... Lists> struct concat;

template <template<typename> class Pred, typename T>
using filter_helper = std::conditional_t<Pred<T>::value, list<T>, list<>>;

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename... Ts> 
using filter = typename concat<filter_helper<Pred, Ts>...>::type;
```

You could implement such a variadic `concat` with recursion:

```
template <>
struct concat<> { using type = list<>; };
template <typename... Ts>
struct concat<list<Ts...>> { using type = list<Ts...>; };
template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat<list<Ts...>, list<Us...>> { using type = list<Ts..., Us...>; };
template<typename... Ts, typename... Us, typename... Rest>
struct concat<list<Ts...>, list<Us...>, Rest...> { using type = typename concat<list<Ts..., Us...>, Rest...>::type; };
```

The above solves your problem in about 16 lines of code, as opposed to 29 lines for your cleaned-up version, as opposed to 42 lines for your original. And the advantage of splitting out the "concatenating lists" subproblem is that there are many different ways to tackle that particular subproblem —

- you could unroll the recursion 3x or even 8x to avoid running so quickly into template-recursion-depth limits
- you could use a compiler builtin (if one exists) to concatenate all the lists at once
- variation on the above: you could delegate the heavy lifting to `tuple_cat`
- or you could Keep It Simple and just use the 8-line version above.

You could benchmark each of these and see which one is most suitable for your expected workload.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and the revised version! Besides the improvements on the content, especially finding the right names  for functionality is often the most important aspect.

Comment: That is surprisingly extremely readable, nice!

Comment: I don't seem to be understanding how to use "filter" to get the first type of the found list. I tried:

template <typename B>
struct my_pred
{
 template <typename T>
 using filter = std::is_base_of<B, T>;
};

filter< my_pred<A>::filter, C, B > v;

But I get:

'v' uses undefined struct 'list<T>'

Comment: @RangelReale: You'd have to implement `first_of` yourself — something like `template<class...> struct first_of_impl; template<class T, class... Rest> struct first_of_impl<T, Rest...> { using type = T; }; template<class... Ts> using first_of = typename first_of_impl<Ts...>::type;`. But then once you've done that, you'd get your final answer by `using answer = first_of<filter<my_pred<A>::filter, C, B>>;`.

Comment: I don't understand why we need four `concat` not two like other recursive implementation for metaprogramming.

Answer (score 3):

The first issue I see is the name of your struct, `list`.  This is problematic - supposing you eventually put this into its own hpp/cpp file, someone may someday try to link to a file that has the line `using std::list;`.  Even beyond that, the name may be confusing at first glance - either rename it or use a namespace (or both).

When I see `using`s like this

```
using list_rename = typename list_rename_impl<source, TargetT>::type;
```

I like to name the aliased type as `type_name_t`, so in this case `list_rename_t`.

You can also use `std::conditional_t<B, T, F>` instead of `std::conditional<B, T, F>::type` [since C++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

This is being pedantic, but the comment here is inaccurate, `C` is a class.

```
//The actual testcase struct
template <typename ... Args>
class C
```

I don't find comments like

```
//~END list_rename
```

to be at all helpful - you use this format consistently, so maybe this is required stylistically, or you have some documentation generating tool, or whatever, but unless you have a compelling reason to have this sort of comment its just noise.

Do you have a compelling reason to require the user to say

```
using ATuple = list_rename<As, std::tuple>;
```

Instead of something like this?

```
template <typename source>
using list_rename_as_tuple = typename list_rename_impl<source, std::tuple>::type;

...

using ATuple = list_rename_as_tuple<As>;
```

I guess I haven't thought about the use cases of this enough, but do you need to make this generic enough that the user specifies their result container type?  Would tuple be a common enough destination type that the second alias is helpful?

I'm not sure if it can be reduced to fewer meta-functions, I don't have the bandwidth to really dig into it at the moment, but is there an advantage to that? Right now I find this to be pretty easy to reason about and understand.