# Filter template meta function

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I wrote a simple C++ template meta function for filtering out types from a list not matching a predicate. This is similar to [Filtering variadic template arguments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115740/filtering-variadic-template-arguments) but does pattern matching instead of `std::conditional` with the aim of being faster. To that end no empty typelists are concatenated which should incur less instantiations and be faster according to https://blog.galowicz.de/2016/06/25/cpp_template_type_list_performance

The below code works for all my test cases. Any hints how to make it faster (less template instantiations), smaller, better, ...? (Note: Assume appropriate *_t using-templates)

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct typelist;

template <typename... TLists>
struct concat;
template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
struct concat<typelist<Args1...>, typelist<Args2...>>
{
    using type = typelist<Args1..., Args2...>;
};
template <class Seq1, class Seq2, class... Seqs>
struct concat<Seq1, Seq2, Seqs...> : concat<Seq1, concat_t<Seq2, Seqs...>>
{
};

template <class TList, template <typename> class Cond>
struct filter;
template<bool matches, template <typename> class Cond, typename...>
struct filter_helper;

template<template <typename> class Cond, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct filter_helper<true, Cond, T, Ts...>
{
    using type = concat_t<typelist<T>, filter_t<typelist<Ts...>, Cond>>;
};

template<template <typename> class Cond, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct filter_helper<false, Cond, T, Ts...>
{
    using type = filter_t<typelist<Ts...>, Cond>;
};

template<template <typename> class Cond, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct filter<typelist<T, Ts...>, Cond>
{
    using type = typename filter_helper<Cond<T>::value, Cond, T, Ts...>::type;
};

template<template <typename> class Cond>
struct filter<typelist<>, Cond>
{
    using type = typelist<>;
};
```

Some tests (`TMP_ASSERT` is like `static_assert`):

```
using list1 = tmp::typelist<int, double>;
using list2 = tmp::typelist<float>;
using list3 = tmp::typelist<double>;
using list4 = tmp::typelist<float, double, double>;
using list5 = tmp::typelist<double, float, double>;
using list6 = tmp::typelist<double, double, float>;
using empty = tmp::typelist<>;

template<typename T>
struct is_not_double: std::true_type{};
template<>
struct is_not_double<double>: std::false_type{};

TMP_ASSERT_SAME((tmp::filter_t<list1, is_not_double>), (tmp::typelist<int>));
TMP_ASSERT_SAME((tmp::filter_t<list2, is_not_double>), (tmp::typelist<float>));
TMP_ASSERT_SAME((tmp::filter_t<list3, is_not_double>), (tmp::typelist<>));
TMP_ASSERT_SAME((tmp::filter_t<list4, is_not_double>), (tmp::typelist<float>));
TMP_ASSERT_SAME((tmp::filter_t<list5, is_not_double>), (tmp::typelist<float>));
TMP_ASSERT_SAME((tmp::filter_t<list6, is_not_double>), (tmp::typelist<float>));
TMP_ASSERT_SAME((tmp::filter_t<empty, is_not_double>), (tmp::typelist<>));
```

Note: Code is from a library licensed under BSD 3-Clause.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Ok, sure. I just considered it a minor edit which makes the code shorter and therefore more readable. It did not change any functionality but rather style. Would it be ok, to add a note, that the specialization can be merged with the declaration so it does not need to be considered in the review (it wasn't by now)?

Comment: Sure, that would be fine. Keep in mind though that while you can suggest reviewers focus on something else, they're free to mention it anyway if they feel a need to do so. But nothing wrong with providing a bit of direction.

Answer (score 5):

I find all those `struct`s tricks a bit old-school now...

There is an alternative implementation using `constexpr` functions; I also recommend to use `if constexpr` to make things more readable, but it's doable without it; you just need another overload:

```
template <typename...>
struct Type_list{};

template <typename... T1s, typename... T2s>
constexpr auto concatenate(Type_list<T1s...>, Type_list<T2s...>) {
    return Type_list<T1s..., T2s...>{};
}

template <template <typename> typename Condition, typename Result>
constexpr auto filter_types(Result result, Type_list<>) {
    return result;
}

template <template <typename> typename Condition, typename Result, typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto filter_types(Result result, Type_list<T, Ts...>) {
    if constexpr (Condition<T>{})
        return filter_types<Condition>(concatenate(result, Type_list<T>{}), Type_list<Ts...>{});
    else
        return filter_types<Condition>(result, Type_list<Ts...>{});
}

template <template <typename> typename Condition, typename... Types>
using filtered_types = std::decay_t<decltype(filter_types<Condition>(Type_list<>{}, Type_list<Types...>{}))>;


template<typename T>
struct is_not_double: std::true_type{};
template<>
struct is_not_double<double>: std::false_type{};

template <typename T>
void print_type() {
    puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }

int main() {
    print_type<filtered_types<is_not_double, double, int, char, float*, double, char*, double>>();
}
```

I'd rather have this sort of programming: template programming looks like normal programming, rather than have two subsets of the language apart from each other.

---

Edit: as per request, here's a rewriting of the code without C++ 17 features:

```
template <typename...>
struct Type_list{};

template <typename... T1s, typename... T2s>
constexpr auto concatenate(Type_list<T1s...>, Type_list<T2s...>) {
    return Type_list<T1s..., T2s...>{};
}

template <template <typename> typename Condition, typename Result, typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto filter_types(Result result, Type_list<T, Ts...>, std::true_type)  {
    return filter_types<Condition>(concatenate(result, Type_list<T>{}), Type_list<Ts...>{});
}

template <template <typename> typename Condition, typename Result, typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto filter_types(Result result, Type_list<T, Ts...>, std::false_type) {
    return filter_types<Condition>(result, Type_list<Ts...>{});
}

template <template <typename> typename Condition, typename Result>
constexpr auto filter_types(Result result, Type_list<>) {
    return result;
}

template <template <typename> typename Condition, typename T, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
constexpr auto filter_types(Type_list<Us...> result, Type_list<T, Ts...> lst) {
    return filter_types<Condition>(result, lst, Condition<T>{});
}

template <template <typename> typename Condition, typename... Types>
using type_filter = decltype(filter_types<Condition>(Type_list<>{}, Type_list<Types...>{}));
```

As for a variadic, container agnostic, `concatenate`, here's what you would do with `fold expressions`:

```
template <template <typename> typename Type_container, typename... T1s, typename... T2s>
constexpr auto operator+(Type_container<T1s...>, Type_container<T2s...>) {
    return Type_container<T1s..., T2s...>{};
}

template <typename... Type_lists>
constexpr auto concatenate(Type_lists... type_lists) {
    return (type_lists + ...);
}
```

Without `fold expressions` you need to provide overloads for calls with 0, 1 and more type lists, as you did with your structs.

Comment: I like the struct way because it is clear, that it is only TMP, not callable code, but those ideas are great, thanks! Some questions: a) C++14 only (see tag), could you revise the constexpr-if? b) How'd you implement the concatenate for 1-n lists and bonus: for any generic variadic templates (like `std::tuple`)?  c) `filtered_types` does not take a typelist, which I'd need. I guess another indirection is required? d) why the `decay_t`? Isn't the result always a plain `typelist`? e) except the constexpr-if, all those functions could be left undefined, right? f) any info on performance?

Comment: @Flamefire: I provided some of the answers inside my post. For the other ones: c) yes, d) habits, `decltype` has its quirks and decaying it makes it walk the line. e) I don't believe so but I'm not sure, f) none, alas.

Comment: The `typename` in `template` `template` parameters is a [tag:C++17] [feature](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4051.html).

Comment: Won't the overloaded +-operator become a problem as now we have a function which can (seemingly) add e.g. 2 `std::tuples` but it will return an empty one in all cases? But you are right, the C++14 version looks like my structs:  https://ideone.com/Nz58sb  

I'd be interested in any resources regarding compile-time performance, if anyone has some.

Answer (score 4):

You can halve your `concat` calls by just creating new typelists inline and skipping the intermediate 2-param `concat` objects on rewind.

Should `concat` be callable on empty and single argument lists?

```
template <typename...>
struct concat {};

template <>
struct concat<> {
    using type = typelist<>;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct concat<typelist<Ts...>> {
    using type = typelist<Ts...>;
};

template <typename... Ts0, typename... Ts1, typename... Rest>
struct concat<typelist<Ts0...>, typelist<Ts1...>, Rest...> 
: concat<typelist<Ts0..., Ts1...>, Rest...> {};

// Helper until C++20
template <typename... Ts>
using concat_t = typename concat<Ts...>::type;
```

---

Rather than recursively filtering your list, consider a sequential approach using pack expansion.  To do this, we'll need to exploit a property of concatenation with `typelist`s.  When you concatenate a list with no elements to a list of elements (`concat<typelist<int>, typelist<>>`), the result list remains the same (`typelist<int>`).

First, maps the predicate result (`true`/`false`) to either `typelist<T>` or `typelist<>`.

```
template <bool>
struct filter_if_result {
    template <typename T> using type = typelist<T>;
};

template <>
struct filter_if_result<false> {
    template <typename T> using type = typelist<>;
};
```

Second, pack expand the unfiltered types and apply the predicate to each. Then `concat` the results to merge typelists with the collected elements with the empty typelists.

```
template <template <typename> class Predicate, typename Sequence>
struct filter_if;

template <template <typename> class Predicate, typename... Ts>
struct filter_if<Predicate, typelist<Ts...>> {
    using type = concat_t<
        typename filter_if_result<Predicate<Ts>::value>::template type<Ts>...>;
};

// Helper until C++20
template <template <typename> class Predicate, typename Sequence>
using filter_if_t = typename filter_if<Predicate, Sequence>::type;
```

*Note - `filter_if` is used to differentiate the predicate version from the version that `filter`s on a specific type.*

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for: Improving my code to make it smaller AND faster. Wasn't able to measure a meaningfull difference but less `concat`s are better and the nested template for `filter_if_result` means less instantiations (I guess)

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing it in a namespace? `concat` and `filter` are too simple and generic names.

```
using type = concat_t<typelist<T>, filter_t<typelist<Ts...>, Cond>>;
```

As long as it's the only case you prepend an element to a list it's okay, but on the second occasion you might think of defining `cons`. :)

Oh, and looks like your `concat` accepts at least two arguments.

Comment: Yes it is in a namespace (indicated in the examples, but omitted for brevity). What do you mean by "defining cons"? Define a separate function for prepending instead of concatenating? Might be good, but the concat is more generic (works for any number of typelists)

Comment: Sure, but `cons<Head` is somewhat shorter than `concat<typelist<Head>`